# GitLab CI npm command not found (ubuntu image)

Tags: node.js, linux, gitlab-ci

I want to use node and npm in my CI, but not use the node image for that! It is because I need to be able to run python and stuff. So I want to just use an ubuntu image and install what I need in the script. Somehow it does not work with nodejs. Neither node nor npm seem to be installed.

I have simplified my `.gitlab-ci.yml` for that:

```
image: ubuntu:latest

stages:
    - build

build:
    script:
        - apt-get update -yqq
        - apt-get install -y nodejs
        - npm -v
```

Do you see me doing anything wrong?

Comment: The Ci file is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formerly, I tried installing `nodejs` from core packages of `apt` multiple times like your way. But every time, I found out that `npm` isn't installed. And when I executed command `nodejs -v`, the printed version wasn't what I expected (It was old). It seems `nodejs` package in Debian's core repository hasn't changed over the years.
I suggest to install `nodejs` and `npm` in this way:

```
image: ubuntu:latest

stages:
    - build

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - apt-get update -yqq
        - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
        - apt-get install -y nodejs
        - npm -v
```

**If you need to install another version, for example 10.x, just change setup_12.x with setup_10.x in above URL.**

Comment: `/bin/bash: line 118: sudo: command not found`